# Fixing Websites

Tags: formula, custom-field

I made a formula field that takes the website and cuts off the beginning too make it easier to compare websites in reports. The one problem I ran into is if someone puts in a website as example.com instead of http://example.com Salesforce autofills the http:// but this causes problems with the formula because the formula does not recognize the http:// Salesforce puts in so for 10% of the websites in the new website field are "Blank" which is what happens if salesforce doesn't detect the beginning.  Is there any way to get this formula field with the websites as they are?

```
IF(ISBLANK(Website), "None",
IF(CONTAINS("https://www. ", left(Website,11)), SUBSTITUTE(Website, "https://www.",""),
IF(CONTAINS("http://www. ", left(Website,10)), SUBSTITUTE(Website, "http://www.",""),
IF(CONTAINS("https:// ", left(Website,7)), SUBSTITUTE(Website, "https://",""),
IF(CONTAINS("http://", left(Website,6)), SUBSTITUTE(Website, "http://",""),
IF(CONTAINS("www. ", left(Website,4)), SUBSTITUTE(Website, "www.",""),
"Blank"))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF( 
 CONTAINS(Website, "www."), TRIM(SUBSTITUTE( Website , LEFT(Website, FIND(".", Website)), NULL)),
IF(
 CONTAINS(Website, "http://"), TRIM(SUBSTITUTE( Website , "http://", NULL)),
IF ( 
CONTAINS(Website, "https://"), TRIM(SUBSTITUTE( Website , "http://", NULL)),
Website)))

Comment: I attempted using your formula but ran into some problems with the websites that are entered as http://example.com when users put in the http:// instead of salesforce inputing them. For these instances it displays "com" in the formula field. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I get what your saying let me take another look.

Comment: IF( BEGINS(Website__c, "http://www."),SUBSTITUTE( Website__c, LEFT(Website__c, FIND(".", Website__c)), NULL), 
IF( BEGINS(Website__c, "https://www."),SUBSTITUTE( Website__c, LEFT(Website__c, FIND(".", Website__c)), NULL), 
If( BEGINS(Website__c, "www"), SUBSTITUTE( Website__c, LEFT(Website__c, FIND(".", Website__c)), NULL), 
If( BEGINS(Website__c, "https"), SUBSTITUTE( Website__c,"https://", NULL), 
If( BEGINS(Website__c, "http"), SUBSTITUTE( Website__c, "http://", NULL), 
Website__c)))))

Comment: That's the formula I ended up making off of yours and it worked, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where these are being entered or if you have any validation rules in place at entry (something to consider if you don't). Obviously you already know not all sites use www and there are also ww3 sites, etc.

As I understand your question, you're either creating or using data from formula fields. What you may want to do to work around this issue is use RegEx instead instead of your formulas. That way you can detect the parts that exist in the form you're looking for and remove the parts you don't want. I suggest you try to remember that there are `.cc`, `.biz`, `.net` and various other domain extensions you may want to take into consideration as well when building your RegEx formula.

A great resource with a built-in RegEx formula builder is [G Skinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). I highly recommend the site. It even has a YouTube tutorial on how to use it.